# Save, read and perform inference in C++/Python for a OpenAI trained model

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, openai-gym

I used OpenAI to train a deepq model. After doing

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(tf.get_default_session(), 'my_deepq')
```

I got the following files:

```
my_deepq.data-00000-of-00001
my_deepq.index
checkpoint
my_deepq.meta
```

---

I then need to load this model in two different systems (C++ and python) to do the inference.

For the python part, I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
imported_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_deepq.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    imported_graph.restore(sess, './my_deepq')
```

The codes ran, but I am not sure where the model was loaded and how to do the inference. Could someone please advise.

---

For the C++ side, I will do something like:

```
tensorflow::Session *my_sess;
tensorflow::Status status = tensorflow::NewSession(options, &my_sess);
tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
status = ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), model_path, &graph_def);

status = my_sess->Create(graph_def);
tensorflow::Status status = my_sess->Run({{"My_Input", input_tensor}}, {"My_Output"}, {}, &output_tensor);
```

This approach requires the model to be in BinaryProto format, but I am not sure how to save my model in BinaryProto in python. Could anyone please advise. Thank you!